# How to Save Multiple Check-boxes data to database?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, checkbox

I am not an expert so I'd really appreciate if you are real specific on your answers.

I have this registration form that has a section with lots of check-boxes, and I wondering what the best way is to save this in the database. I am not sure if all values should go to a single column, or If I should create a different table only for this section of my registration form. It's also important to take into account that I will later need to pull all this data from the database and to show it in the "admin back-end" where it would be available for edition to update  the database. Below you can see part of the html code for the section containing the check-boxes.

```
<p>4) Please select only the product(s) you are interested in. (Anticipated purchase amounts for the quarter.)</p>
        <table  cellpadding="15" >
         <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Handbags</th>
      <th>Fashion Jewelry</th>
      <th>Watches</th>
      <th>Crystal Travel Jewelry</th>
      <th>Fine Jewelry</th>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="1" />$2500+ </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="2"  />$1000-$2500 </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="3"  />Up to $1000 </br>    
</td>
  <td>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="4" />$2500+ </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="5"  />$1000-$2500 </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="6"  />Up to $1000 </br>  
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="7" />$2500+ </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="8"  />$1000-$2500 </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="9"  />Up to $1000 </br>  
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="10" />$2500+ </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="11"  />$1000-$2500 </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="12"  />Up to $1000 </br>  
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="13" />$2500+ </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="14"  />$1000-$2500 </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_amount[]" value="15"  />Up to $1000 </br>        
</tr>

  </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>5) What are the average retail price points for each of the following items? (Check only those that apply.)</p>
        <table  cellpadding="15" >
         <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Handbags</th>
      <th>Jewelry</th>
      <th>Watches</th>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]" value="1" />$125 or greater<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]" value="2"  />$75</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]" value="3"  /> $40</br>    
</td>
  <td>
<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]" value="4" />$125 or greater<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]" value="5"  />$75</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]" value="6"  /> $40</br>    
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]" value="7" />$125 or greater<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]" value="8"  />$75</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]" value="9"  /> $40</br>     
</tr>
      </tbody>
        </table>
```

[Jsfiddle Demo if that helps.](http://jsfiddle.net/codekmarv/9uNuB/)!

Thanks a lot in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options…
1)Allowing one box to be checked per category:
In this case, it would be better if you changed your checkboxes to radio buttons that way it is easier to keep only one checked at one time and you will only have to store the value of the one button selected in one column of your database.
2)Allowing multiple boxes to be checked per category:
In this case, you can keep your checkboxes and would suggest storing the total value of the checkboxes in one column to keep the load on your database down. However, this means that you need to include some form of script reverse the addition you did before storing the info in your database. You could do this by having the values of the three check boxes in each category be 1, 10 and 100 so that you could easily check which ones were checked by using a series of % operations.
`<table  cellpadding="15" >`
`<tbody>`
`<tr>`
`<th>Handbags</th>`
`<th>Jewelry</th>`
`<th>Watches</th>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td>`
`<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]1" value="1" />$125 or greater<br />`
`<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]1" value="10"  />$75<br />`
`<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]1" value="100"  /> $40<br />`
`</td>`
`<td>`
`<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]2" value="1" />$125 or greater<br />`
`<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]2" value="10"  />$75<br />`
`<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]2" value="100"  /> $40<br />`
`<td>`
`<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]3" value="1" />$125 or greater<br />`
`<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]3" value="10"  />$75<br />`
`<input type="checkbox" name="av_rtp[]3" value="100"  /> $40<br />`
`</tr>`
`</tbody>`
`</table>`
*Notice how each group has a different name, to keep them separated. You should do this whether you use radio buttons or checkboxes since they mean different things.
Let me know if this helps or not.

Comment: On the second option, it would mean adding three new columns to the database only for that question, right? I would have to add av_rtp[]1, av_rtp[]2, and av_rtp[]3. You said it's better for checking later which checkboxes where selected by using % operation. could please explain or give an example of what an % operation is?  If on the other hand, I choose to save all values to only one column in the database using values from 1 to 9, for example, is it gonna be difficult to pull the values from the database to show them in the edition page? Thanks a lot for your answer by the way.

Comment: What I meant by having av_rtp[]1, av_rtp[]2 and av_rtp[]3 is that you would like input for all of those values separate. For instance, you want to know how much they wan to spend on specifically handbags, fashion jewelry, watches, crystal travel jewelry and fine jewelry. Which means that they won't necessarily have the same value. By giving them different names in the form means that you are able to keep those values separate. Having numbers range from 1-9 is difficult to use because 1+2=3 which could be the same as just getting 3 as a preference. 123%100=23… 23%10=3…Does that help? @codekmarv

Comment: Thanks. I think this is  a little above my level of understanding, but I'm already enjoying to learn about it. Thanks. Based on your suggestion, it means that I wouldn't have to create a column for each checkbox, and that's exactly what I trying to do. I am still trying to figure out the table structure I should use, since I've decided that this should definitely go in a different table (retailers) and not my default customer table.

Answer (score 3):

It is an extremely poor practice to store a delimited list of data in one column. It creates querying issues (and performance issues when you have to query using a nonsargable where clause). Create a separate table.

Comment: Ok, agreed. Which table structure would you suggest? I already have my customer table where I store all the basic info requested in the registration form. So I guess I would have to create a new table to store all the info from this section [ This section of the registration form is only for people who are applying for a retailer account]

Comment: That is correct create a new related table that contains the customer id and any other fields you need. Make sure to create a foreign key relationships.

Comment: Ok,  I was wondering if you could take a look at my registration form, and help me to design the new tables. I guess I would need at least one new table, but what do you suggest in regards to the checkboxes? would I have create a new column in this new table for each of them? If yes, wouldn't that be the same as crowding up my original customer table?